# How can show time in tree regression plot

Tags: r, plot

I want to obtain the same graph as below:
[image]

for this I write these codes:

```
library(quantmod)
library(tree)
symbols=c('^GSPC')
getSymbols(symbols,src="yahoo", from="2001-01-02", to="2011-08-22")
period="daily" 
df<-as.data.frame(GSPC)
df<-cbind(date=as.Date(rownames(df)),df)
Ndata<-df[,c(1,7)]
A<-abs(log(Ndata[,2]/Lag(Ndata[,2])))
Ntree<-tree(A~as.ts(Ndata[,1]))
plot(Ntree)
text(Ntree,cex=0.75)
```

and obtain this plot:

[image]

How can I get the same label (the time that showed in the first plot) to my plot like the first one?

Comment: Is there any label option in the library reference?

Comment: @Llopis, yes. I used label option on `text` and nothing happend